# PayPal Webhook not firing in Sandbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a webhook set up in my sandbox account. I'm using the C# SDK in a .NET MVC5 project.

I've got an endpoint that it is pointing to (set to receive a POST request) in my site.

I'm using the REST API and I want to cover the following:

`Payment sale completed, 
Payment sale denied, 
Payment sale pending, 
Payment sale refunded, 
Payment sale reversed`

When I purchase a subscription on my site everything goes through and I can see the event for the `Payment.Sale.Completed` in my PayPal developer console.

If I fire over the JSON from the developer console directly to my site everything works.

My webhook is set up on a `https` URL.

I have disabled the Request validation in my webhook endpoint (for testing).

I have tried setting up the webhook for 'ALL' and the above events.

When I click `Resend` in the paypal dev console nothing happens. It just doesn't seem to hit my website endpoint ever! Please help!

Comment: ...update...curiously, I've pushed my code to live and the webhook instantly worked. Is this just 'broken' in Sandbox mode? #wastedday

Comment: ...update...nearly a month after originally trying to get sandbox webhooks to fire they all started pouring in one day. :/